# What is the difference between >0 and >=1?

Tags: syntax

The title says it all. Is there any reason why some professors and programmers in general write

```
if ( x >= 1 )
```

instead of

```
if ( x > 0 )
```

?

Comment: If `x` is integer, none. If `x` is a float/double/etc then the second would be true also for any `x > 0` but `x < 1`. The first wouldn't.

Comment: What is the data type of your variable?

Comment: we don't even know what kind of language is that how you people can start typing replies ?

Comment: The example our professor used right now was of an Integer type, but it's not the first time I've seen this, my employer did this with ints as well.

Comment: in general, I use `>` over `>=` every time.

Comment: If this isn't about possible data type difference - it's about personal preferences. And, for example, in my case, for integers I'll use `>0` (and save 1 char)

Comment: Professors aren't known for their great coding practices `;-)`. And neither are most programmers, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a performance consideration here- a CPU can in some circumstances compare with 0 faster than with 1. A clever compiler might be able to optimize this, but comparing to 0 is generally a better practice where possible.

EDIT: A bit of clarification on this-
Processors have a 'zero' flag that gets set when the result of an arithmetic operation or compare instruction results in a value of zero. There's also a 'negative' flag as well. A 'compare' instruction is actually more or less identical to a 'subtract' instruction, except the result is not stored, but the flags are set.

It does depend on context, but if that variable had just been set as a result of an arithmetic operation, and it's now 0, the zero flag will already have been set, and no compare instruction is necessary to determine if x > 0. When it's 1, it's necessary to do a compare with the constant of 1 to set the zero flag, and satisfy the condition.

For (pseudocode) example, some compilers (I've seen Delphi do this) will optimize

```
for x = 0 to 10 { print "hello world " }
```

to

```
for x = 10 down to 0 { .. }
```

simply because it doesn't need to do 'compare x with 10' every time, as the zero flag is already set on the last iteration as a result of decrementing x. Of course it can only do this if x isn't referenced within the loop, otherwise it'll change the functionality.

Wikipedia's got further clarification on the 'zero' flag: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_flag

Comment: Really? Which CPU and whith which conditions and with which compilers?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to see some proof to back up this claim

Comment: It's pretty much a general thing. To compare with anything other than 0, a processor will subtract one value from the other, and set zero/negative flags based on the result, although probably not store the result anywhere. I'll dig something out when I can.

Comment: if you go to assembler, there is a difference between `branch if zero` and `branch if condition`, but most compiler would know how to properly compare to a constant.

Comment: Such things __can not__ be claimed as "general things" - it's very, very specific

Comment: I'll look out some information how how a CPU does a compare instruction when I can, but a good example I've encountered is Delphi's optimization of a 'for' loop from 0 to n, where the loop variable is not referenced. The compiler will optimize it to n downto 0, simply because it's cheaper for the cpu to compare with 0 than n.

Comment: There is the way CPU does the comparison and the way the compiler reads your code. Compilers are very clever things. These 2 instructions being equivalent, I am fairly certain most modern compiler would translate them the same way.

Comment: @AlmaDo: The presence of a 'zero' flag pretty much is a general thing. I don't know any CPUs that don't work this way.

Answer (score 4):

if both are integers, there's no difference

Comment: Yet I see professors do it all the time. I would expect there to be some degree of merit to this, considering the use of an additional character.

Comment: @krystah - It's cleaner if you're working with a mix of datatypes.  With >0 there can be confusion as to what you're expecting (Is it an int and you're looking for 1+, or is it a float that can be less than 1?) whereas with >=1 you know that no matter the datatype, you're looking for something that is 1+.  If I'm working with only Integers, I go shorthand, but if I'm mixing types in my code, I go with the longer version

Comment: the OP doesn't even specifies what language is this, how you can offer such response ?

Answer (score 1):

Using one or the other makes no difference technically (granted x is an integer, which apparently it is).

However, choosing one comparison over the other may hold semantic meaning. One says:

> Do this action is there are more than 0 `X`es. I can work on any positive amount of items

The other says

> Do this action is there is at least 1 `X`. I cannot do this action if there is not a least 1 item

They have the same meaning, but expressed in a different way, that can help understand why you are comparing to such value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of `x`. If it is of an integral type, they're the same and it is a personal preference. I'd always go with the shortest `x > 0`. However, if it is of a float/fixed point number type, then there is a big difference as there are many values between 0 and 1.

However, there could be two reasons why people choose one over another:

1) For clarity of intention: If the requirement is "give me an integer from one and up", then they use `x >= 1`, while if the requirement is "give me a positive integer", then they use `x > 0`. Now when you're reading the code later on, you can easily figure the requirements and intentions. I see this specially useful in school to make it clear while students are still learning.

2) Some developers don't know what they're doing and are confused even about the basics, so they implement the requirements literally like above without analysing the impact on performance, security, etc. In our example here, there is really no harm, but in some other code, there could be a huge difference and I've seen many developers who just don't know the difference and impact.